# Option for User to edit their own Profile

Tags: users

Is it possible for the user to be able to edit their own profile without going through the Drupal administration panel?  I have a /user page with views that output the needed fields.  Ideally I would like an 'edit profile' button that loads up the same editable fields.

Could someone point me to how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance,

P.S.: I'm on Drupal 7. Might be worth noting that I'm using *Profile 2* as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution to this problem.  I have to call the 'edit user' link directly from Views as a field.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't give users the permission to use the admin theme they will only ever see the regular theme, regardless of what page they are on.

So you could do that and then just link to the profile edit page.

The user will never know they are in the administration area. They just see a form they can fill out.

Is that an acceptable solution?